# Collinear points in 3dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, matlab, 3d, computational-geometry

Given three $3D$ points: $A,B$ and $C$, what is the procedure to check if they are collinear?

In general, given $n$ points in $m$-dimension, how should one find out, if these $n$-points defines a hyperplane of dimension $m'$, where $m' \lt m$. And what should be the relationship between $n$ and $m$, if we are looking for hyperplanes of strictly smaller dimension.

And is there any general/efficient way in MatLab, to find this?

Comment: Note: due to rounding error, $A,B,C$ are *not* collinear with probability 1, even if you want them to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

subtract one point from every other point to get $n-1$ vectors. Then put these vectors as columns into a matrix and compute the rank of the matrix (e.g. in Matlab), and this is the dimension of the hyperplane the points lie on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also if you can please explain the intuition behind this procedure, that would be really great. Like why do we want to subtract one point from every other point, why should we place the vectors as column vectors and what is the relationship between collinearity of the points and the rank of this matrix.

Comment: @Shambo The dimensionality of the hyperplane through the points is the dimensionality when the hyperplane is shifted to become a subspace, which is why you subtract one point from the others so that $0$ becomes a point hence the hyperplane is a subspace. As for why rank is the answer, look up the dimensionality of the image of a linear operator (matrix). This is equal to the number of linearly independent rows, which is the rank.