# Check Vector3 points on one line using a Matrix

Tags: matrices, vectors, determinant, 3d

I know that for 3 Vector2 points (say points `a`, `b`, `c`)  the determinant of the following matrix `M` is zero if they are one one line:

```
    | ax  ay  1 |
M = | bx  by  1 |
    | cx  cy  1 |
```

But how can I check this for 3 Vector3 points. I wrongly assumed it would be like this:

```
    | ax  ay  az |
M = | bx  by  bz |
    | cx  cy  cz |
```

Is there a similar way to determine that 3 points (Vector3) are on one line in 3D using a matrix and the determinant?

Comment: I think this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759448/collinear-points-in-3dimension  might help you .

Answer (score 0):

3 Points A B and C are in one line (collinear) in 3D if:

```
→    →    →
AB × AC = 0

AB = A.sub( B );
AC = A.sub( C );

vector = AB.cross( BC );

collinear = vector.x === 0 && vector.y === 0 && vector.z === 0
```

collinear is `true` for points in one line, `false` if not in one line.

To keep into account any rounding errors or inaccuracies in the vectors it can be necessary to set a precision and use the absolute values:

```
precision = 0.0001; // set some presision
collinear = |vector.x| < precision && |vector.y| < precision && |vector.z| < precision
```

Different syntax:

```
precision = 0.0001; // set some presision
collinear = abs(vector.x) < precision && abs(vector.y) < precision && abs(vector.z) < precision;
```

---

Another way is to calculate the surface area of a triangle using those three points A, B and C. They are collinear when the surface is equal to zero:

```
area = 0.5 * ( Ax * ( By - Cy ) + Bx * ( Cy - Ay ) + Cx * ( Ay - By ) )

collinear = ( area === 0 )
```

Or

```
precision = 0.0001
collinear = | area | < precision
```